# inetloc files broken in Mojave 10.14.2

Tags: shortcut, mojave, url

I usually distribute *inetloc* files to people who need to occasionally access shared drives... they're super convenient, and, since their existence, it's been possible to *include passwords* (though in plain text)..
For those who don't know what I'm talking about, open TextEdit, type in the following:

```
smb://login:password@address/Sharepoint
```

then select the whole thing, drag it to the desktop and, voilà, you've got a ready-made shortcut to your shared drive!

**The Problem Is: as of 10.14.2, Mojave ignores the included password and puts up a password dialog**, which defeats the whole purpose of these shortcuts..
Indeed, the problem is that these shortcuts can include the password without the user having to ever re-enter it

(Additionally, inetloc files have never worked to mount NFS shares)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the only solution now is to create an AppleScript app (using Script Editor) with the following command:

```
tell application "Finder" to mount volume "smb://login:password@address/Sharepoint"
```

note that this works with nfs shares too -- even though inetloc files never did...

Alternatively, you can use the command:

```
tell application "Finder" to open location
```

but that no longer works with nfs shares since 10.14.2 either

Answer (score 1):

To build on what Peter said, this is the code snipped I use in my bash script:

```
/usr/bin/osascript > /dev/null << EOT

       tell application "Finder" 
       activate
       mount volume "smb://login:password@address/Sharepoint"
       end tell

EOT
```